# Recommended time length of press debouncing/release debouncing with buttons of Basys3 FPGA

Tags: fpga, vhdl, debouncing

I am doing an algorithmic state machine in VHDL. It models a slot machine. It uses debouncing for the start and end input signals. I need to implement it later on a Basys 3 FPGA.  The start and end input signals are modeled with the FPGA buttons. The frequency of the CLK signal of the Basys3 FPGA is 100 MHz. Therefore the period of CLK must be 10^-8 seconds= 10*10^-9 seconds = 10 ns.

- What time length do you recommend for the press debouncing time when pressing the  buttons of the Basys3?
- What time length do you recommend for the release debouncing time when releasing the buttons of the Basys3?

Comment: Most types of switches stop bouncing within 10 ms.

Comment: what buttons?  link?  If you make your design edge triggered and consider the max user toggle rate of maybe 10 Hz, the dead time after start could be 50ms  but contact bounce time might only be 1 to 5ms and faulty is > 10ms. Then bounce time is irrelevant unless you  ignore user dwell or toggle   time .

Comment: How is Start stop computed?  press or release to start SPIN

Comment: There are two buttons. One of them for starting the slot machine and another one to stop it.

Comment: Consider 10ms for fastest detection time and 50 ms hold time for longest wait time to ignore glitches from potential EMI

Comment: Would it help it someone win if they detected FPGA clock and sent a transient to trigger switch synchronously every 1e8 + x cycles?

Comment: Well, I had set up 50 miliseconds as press debouncing time because I had seen somewhere that as recommended time but I was not sure. Thanks for confirming. Anyway that makes the simulation to take really long. 10 ms as Dave Tweed suggested is slightly less but I guess it will also take quite a while to simulate the slot machine with that debouncing time.
 In order to overcome this problem: Should I simulate with shorter debouncing time and then increase the debouncing time before synthesizing and imlementing the circuit on the FPGA?

Comment: "How is Start stop computed? press or release to start SPIN"--->>>
Answer:
Once press debouncing time, of the button chosen as start button, has gone by, the start signal is computed.
Once press debouncing time, of the button chosen as end button, has gone by, the end signal is computed.

Comment: "Would it help it someone win if they detected FPGA clock and sent a transient to trigger switch synchronously every 1e8 + x cycles?"--->I do not know, I do not understand the question really well. What I know is: the slot machine has two mod-10 counters which count with different speeds: counter 1 and counter 2. Each of them address BRAM1 and BRAM2 respectively. These BRAM memories are initializaed with number 0 to 9 in their 10 locations but each number is stored in a random position on each BRAM. Once the start button is pressed, the counters start counting.Once the end button is pressed...

Comment: ...Once the end button is pressed, the values of the locations of BRAM 1 and BRAM 2 addressed by the counters are compared. If the values addressed by the counters are equal, then you get a prize. Otherwise, you get no prize. I hope I replied all questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127199/discussion-between-goahead97-and-tony-stewart-ee75).

Answer (score 1):

> *There are two buttons. One of them for starting the slot machine and
> another one to stop it.*

So, if the start button activates immediately and then bounces for several ms who cares - it's not until the stop button is pressed that you need to take any subsequent action and, that can happen immediately as well. Of course, if some fool is pressing both (and that's a problem) then you need to do some thinking about the situation but, I don't see that de-bouncing will help you in that scenario either.

De-bouncing is only really necessary in applications like telephone keypads where multiple false presses will cause a number to be mis-dialled.